# tensorflow not supported wheel on this platform

Tags: tensorflow

I've searched around and non of the solutions seem to pertain to me, so here I am.

I installed anaconda 5.1 for python 3.6, I downloaded and installed 64-Bit(x86)Installer(551 MB)

from

https://www.anaconda.com/download/#linux

I followed the directions here

https://docs.anaconda.com/anaconda/install/linux

I had the install prepend the path and install microsoft VS code.

I then attempt to install the CPU only tensorflow using anaconda as suggested here

https://www.tensorflow.org/install/install_linux#InstallingAnaconda

I try to install the binary for python 3.6 CPU only

https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/linux/cpu/tensorflow-1.6.0-cp36-cp36m-linux_x86_64.whl

I get the following error

tensorflow-1.6.0-cp36-cp36m-linux_x86_64.whl is not a supported wheel on this platform.

I am running a Ubuntu 16.04 VM on windows 10.

edit: when I run this command

pip install --ignore-installed --upgrade tfBinaryURL

outside of the tensorflow environment it worked.

2nd edit:

Additionally I explored my tensorflow environment in my anaconda3 folder, and I noticed it only has python 2.7, so when I tried to install the cpu only tensorflow while in the enviroment for python 2.7 it worked.

Comment: So, it's solved ? :)

Comment: Yes, it appears so, I even have it working on sublime text somehow :D

Comment: Haha that's great! Otherwise I would have suggested you to try `conda install -c conda-forge tensorflow `. Enjoy tensorflow!